# Какое слово образовано бессуфиксальным способом?

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор

Слово *вынес* или *обитатели*?

Мне кажется *вынес*. Объясните почему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует способ образования "нулевая суффиксация", например: зеленый - зелень, но приведенные слова к этому способу не имеют отношения.

Слова "вынес" и "обитатели" - это формы слов "вынести" и "обитатель". Они образуются следующим образом: нести - вынести (префиксальный способ) и обитать - обитатель (суффиксальный способ).

Answer (score 4):

София совершенно права, автор вопроса поторопился принять ответ.

Ищите другое слово. Бессуфиксным способом (=бессуфиксальным, способом нулевой суффиксации) образуются только существительные! От глагола или от прилагательного. Может, там не "вынес" а "вынос", тогда да, от глагола выносить.

Answer (score 1):

Слово ВЫНЕС не может быть образовано бессуффиксным (или бессуффиксальным ) способом по той простой причине, что в слове вынес есть суффикс, он нулевой. Так как это глагол в форме прошедшего времени, он ОБЯЗАН иметь суффикс Л. Докажем, что суффикс нулевой есть: вынес-л-а, вынес-л-о, вынес-л-и. При изменении формы рода и числа появляется суффикс прошедшего времени и окончание.
Таким образом, в слове ВЫНЕС есть нулевой суффикс и нулевое окончание.
Я согласна с Софией, вынес - способ префиксальный.
Хочу уточнить, обращаясь к Лаpf, что бессуффиксный способ словообразования и способ нулевой аффиксации - вещи разные.